Ng-Select - Set multiple dropdown values
we are using NG-SELECT trying a create multiple forms with drop-down , we are trying to update the value of all dropdowns when one of the dropdown is updated but unable to find the correct node or configuration option to set it.
//reusable-form.component.ts
.. some inputs here
<ng-select 
      [searchable]="false"
      [clearable]="false"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
      placeholder="search"
      (change)="onSelect($event)"
    >
      <ng-option *ngFor="let data of datas; trackBy:userByName [value]="data.name">
      {{
        data.name
      }}
     </ng-option>
</ng-select>
 

we tried setting the option on change event as below, but the values are updated on rest of the drop-downs
onSelect(event){
    this.selectedOption = event ; // even though model already has the value in it
    this.cdref.detectchanges();
}


please share working example on stackblitz with the issue happening, replication steps and expected result

@NarenMurali ,here you go :  https://angular-are8kq-tzhjcfcr.stackblitz.io , thanks !

We can use @Output to emit an event outside the component with the select (selectionChange), when the value changes ngModelChange will fire, we use the emit method of the event emitter, to send the data up to the parent element.
<ng-select
  [items]="accounts"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="name"
  [searchable]="false"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount"
  (ngModelChange)="selectionChange.emit($event)"
>
</ng-select>

We define the @Output as below:
export class GroupDefaultExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() index: string;
  @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

Now on the parent component, we listen for this event (selectionChange) using event binding () and call the selectAll method.
We take a ViewChildren which you can think of as an array like structure of all the components GroupDefaultExampleComponent inside the parent.
Using this viewchildren, we loop through the elements using forEach and set the selected property using the selected value.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
      <h2>Need to set all values as same once selected in anyone of dropdowns</h2>
      <div style="margin-top:50px" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">
        <group-default-example #group [index]="i" (selectionChange)="selectAll($event);">
        </group-default-example>
      </div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(GroupDefaultExampleComponent)
  groups: QueryList<GroupDefaultExampleComponent>;

  selectAll(selectedAccount: string) {
    this.groups.forEach((group: GroupDefaultExampleComponent) => {
      group.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

thanks @naren murali , above worked .. only downside we are noticing when using with complex componenet is that the update on selected option is not reflecting instanteously as opposed to the stackblitz, any idea wat could be reason as we tried to use detect changes manually as well but not efficient  selectAll(selectedAccount: string) {     this.groups.forEach((group: GroupDefaultExampleComponent) => {       group.selectedAccount = selectedAccount; this.cd.detectChanges()     });

@Hari do you have change detection on push turned on? maybe call cdr.detectChanges() after the forEach loop, to solve the problem?

thanks ! fixed with ngDocheck() ngDoCheck() {     if (this.selectedOption !== this.updatedOption) {       this.selectedOption = this.updatedOption;       this.cd.detectChanges();     }   } .. let me know if u see any downside to this approach as it looks like a overkill but didnt want to changedetection from onpush as its spartacus out of box component
